# c# как распаралелить задачу, чтобы она выполнялась три раза

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность, parallel

Я создаю циклом задачи, в результате я должен получить
1 скачалась
2 скачалась
3 скачалась
Но вместо этого я получаю
1 скачалась
1 скачалась
1 скачалась
То есть данные в этих запущенных задачах не меняются. Хочу получить результат как у многих программ, запуск в потоках, то есть одна задача выполняется много раз и при это разный результат

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Leaf.xNet;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;

namespace Создание_потоков
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private string Random_name()
        {
            string image = "";
            var r = new Random();
            while (image.Length < 12)
            {
                Char c = (char)r.Next(33, 125);
                if (Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))
                    image += c;
            }
            return image;
        }
        void Download_Image()
        {
                string image_name = Random_name();
                HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
                request.KeepAlive = true;
                request.UserAgentRandomize();
                var bytes = request.Get("https://thiscatdoesnotexist.com/").ToBytes();
                File.WriteAllBytes(image_name + ".jpeg", bytes);
                Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { textBox1.AppendText(image_name + " Скачалась" + Environment.NewLine); });
        }
        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>(); // список задач
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) // Добавляем циклом задачи, но выполняется как будто один развыполнилась, данные не меняются
            {

                tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => { Download_Image(); }));
            }
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks); // ждем всё
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А чего просто 3 раза не вызвать?

Comment: Если вызвать три раза, то выполнится последовательно, а мне нужно параллельно, чтобы была работа одновременная для ускорения получения данных, этот код взят  за пример, чтобы понять как это работает.

Comment: ну так вы не ждите таски по одному. Создайте 3 таска, а потом эти три таска ждите - вот они и будут работать параллельно.

Comment: Да можно создать их и они будут работать. Но суть в том что, чтобы получить результат как у многих  программ. Например запустить задачу в 50 потоках или 30 потоках и чтобы это выполнялось одновременно. С массивом потоков у меня не вышло, в этом я не разобрался как реализовать запуск потоков, они у меня циклятся.. Если я запускаю следующим кодом

Comment: var task = new Task(Download_Image);
            Task[] t = new Task[3];
            for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)
            {
                t[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(Download_Image);
            }

Comment: То у меня задача выполняется, но результат  не радует, то есть задача выполнилась не как три отдельных потока, а как будто я зациклил.                   
QOFPiuWE1D8g Скачалась
QOFPiuWE1D8g Скачалась
QOFPiuWE1D8g Скачалась

Comment: Обновите код в вопросе

Comment: Может такая задача не тасками делается, а потоками, не пойму.

Comment: Это ASP.NET? Что за приложение?

Comment: C# Windows Forms, библиотека LeafXnet для работы с запросами. Взял в пример скачивание картинок, что бы ощутить параллельное выполнение задачи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы просто запутались в этих тасках. Все намного проще. Единственное, чтобы обновлять содержимое текстбокса из стороннего потока, я стащил один метод [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519233).

```csharp
private Random rndGen = new Random();

private string Random_name()
{
    string image = "";
    while (image.Length < 12)
    {
        lock(rndGen)
        {
            Char c = (char)rndGen.Next(33, 125);
        }
        if (Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))
            image += c;
    }
    return image;
}

private void Download_Image()
{
    string image_name = Random_name(); // избегайте глобальных переменных при многопоточной работе
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.KeepAlive = true;
    request.UserAgentRandomize();
    var bytes = request.Get("https://thiscatdoesnotexist.com/").ToBytes();
    File.WriteAllBytes(image_name + ".jpeg", bytes);
    AppendTextBox(image_name + " Скачалась" + Environment.NewLine);
}

private void AppendTextBox(string value)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action<string>(AppendTextBox), new object[] { value });
        return;
    }
    textBox1.Text += value;
}

// async обработчик, чтобы не морозить интерфейс, пока работают таски
// хотя можно было бы и без async и не ждать
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>(); // список задач
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    { 
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(Download_Image)); // добавляем задачу
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks); // ждем все
    textBox1.Text += "Всё скачалось" + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Comment: QFmzy4Ijbjtf Скачалась
QFmzy4Ijbjtf Скачалась
QFmzy4Ijbjtf Скачалась
Всё скачалось Проблема осталась таже, как будто не в разных задачах выполняется,  а в одной и одновременно.

Comment: @ИванРудаков исправил код на глобальный рандом генератор. Скорее всего проблема в нём.

Comment: Я с вашим кодом попробовал, результат с него. Метод для выхода из потока, чтобы обратиться к элементу формы и написать текст удобный)

Comment: Самое забавное если использовать этот способ, то все работает, но нельзя управлять тасками, способ такой не очень хороший.                                                                           await Task.Run(() => {
       Download_Image();
    });

Comment: @ИванРудаков Я только что изменил код метода `Random_name` и на то что над ним обратите анимание. :)

Comment: Я заметил изменения в коде)

Comment: @ИванРудаков что вы имеете в виду под "управлять тасками"

Comment: @ИванРудаков вы удалили глобальную переменную `image_name`?

Comment: Да удалил и перевел рандом как в вашем коде в string

Comment: @ИванРудаков тогда я перестаю понимать, что происходит. Добавьте новый код в вопрос. Только не удаляйте старый, а ниже допишите с пометкой "обновлено" и обозначьте там текущую проблему.

Comment: Обновил код и описание проблемы

Comment: @ИванРудаков ваш метод рандома отличается от того что в ответе.

Comment: Точно, после изменения вашего,  проглядел код. Хоть вы и сказали об этом. Спасибо большое) То есть нужно блокировать остальные потоки, чтобы они не могли обращаться к данным одновременно?

Comment: @ИванРудаков если речь о рандоме, то да, потому что он не потокобезопасный.

Comment: Проблема решена, еще раз спасибо) Поизучаю еще про блокировки потоков, ведь это как в магазине, продавец одновременно не может обслужить всех покупателей, так как не сможет и нужно выставить очередь. Завтра попробую в основном коде, а не в этом примере. Как я читал если запустить потоки они могут обращаться к цепочки методов в разной последовательности? То есть  у меня много методов и данных, если использовать несколько потоков, логика программы не должна же нарушиться?

Comment: @ИванРудаков нарушиться может что угодно, если без осознания принципов работы многопоточности подойти к реализации. Спасибо, успехов. :)